# Understanding nested loop and classes

Tags: java, class, loops

I started a project to understand deeply nested loops and classes. In my CYCLING method when I reach the if(y >= 0) loop it doesn't properly use my variables in classes. For example if MPH is 15 and the gear is 1 or 3 it won't ask me to change gear. Or if gear is 1 and speed is 11+ it wont ask me to change gear? What am I doing incorrectly?

---

```
public class Bike {
    int speed;
    int gear;

    void changeGear(int newVal) {
        gear = newVal;
    }

    void speedUp(int newVal) {
        speed = newVal;
    }

    void breaks(int slow) {
        speed = speed + slow;
    }

    void printState() {
        System.out.println("Gear is: " + gear);
        System.out.println("Speed is: " + speed + ("MPH"));
    }
}

//________________________

public static boolean cycle = true;
public static Bike b1 = new Bike();
public static int x;
public static int y;
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int choice;

//______________________________

public static void cycling() {
    while (cycle == true) {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now? Enter a number.");
        System.out.println("1: Speed Change");
        System.out.println("2: Change Gear");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Choose a speed change");
            y = input.nextInt();
            if (y < 0) {
                b1.breaks(y);
                if (b1.speed < 0) {
                    b1.speed = Math.abs(y) + y;
                    System.out.println("You've stopped entirely");
                }
            }
            if (y >= 0) {
                b1.speed = y;
                b1.printState();
                if (b1.speed >= 0 && b1.speed <= 10) {
                    while (b1.gear != 1) {
                        System.out.println("You need to be in Gear 1 for " + "that! Please change gears.");
                        x = input.nextInt();
                        b1.changeGear(x);
                    }
                    if (b1.speed >= 11 && b1.speed <= 20) {
                        while (b1.gear != 2) {
                            System.out.println("You need to be in Gear 2 for" + "that! Please change gears.");
                            x = input.nextInt();
                            b1.changeGear(x);
                        }
                        if (b1.speed >= 21) {
                            while (b1.gear != 3) {
                                System.out.println("You need to be in Gear 3 for" + "that! Please change gears.");
                                x = input.nextInt();
                                b1.changeGear(x);
                            }
                        }
             /*if(b1.speed >= 0 && b1.speed <=10){
                 b1.gear = 1;
             }else if(b1.speed >= 11 && b1.speed <=20){
                 b1.gear = 2;
             }else if(b1.speed >= 21){
                 b1.gear = 3;
             }*/
                        b1.printState();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use your IDE to format your code so it is easier to read.  I also suggest that when you have a bug you use your debugger to step through your code so you can find the line which doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: Debugger did not find anything but I did format it.

Comment: In that case every line behaves as you expect it to and you don't have a problem....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about your statements. You have something that basically looks like this:

```
if (b1.speed >= 0 && b1.speed <= 10) {
    //some while loop here to do whatever
    if (b1.speed >= 11 && b1.speed <= 20) {
        //more code
    }
}
```

In your code, this statement will never be true:

```
if (b1.speed >= 11 && b1.speed <= 20) {
```

The only way you get to that statement is if b1.speed>=0 && b1.speed<=10. Therefore, will b1.speed ever be between 11 and 20 when you get to that second (nested) if statement?

Comment: Oh wow I didn't notice I did that. Probably accident brackets in wrong places. I'll give that a try after school and give you an update.

Comment: You're right, it essentially translates to `(b1.speed >= 0 && b1.speed <= 10) && (b1.speed >= 11 && b1.speed <= 20)`

Comment: @David This is the reason why it's good practice to format a code. You don't have to analyse brackets, you just see when something is wrong.